# Maintain listview state when item is clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a fragment(parent) that contains a tabhost with two tabs.Each tab is a fragment which contains a listview.When the parent fragment is accessed the first time,the two listview fragments load ok as seen below.

[image]
 [image]

Problem is when eaither of the listview item is clicked.After being redirected to the clicked item details,on pressing the back button the two listviews are empty and no longer displayed.Here is what i mean
[image]

I want to display the listviews just as they were before i clicked an item.How can i achieve that?Suggestions will be highly appreciated.
The code for the each of the two fragments:

```
public class AvailableDriversFragment extends Fragment implements
    OnItemClickListener, OnScrollListener {
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
ArrayList<Driver> adverts;
TextView loadingmore;

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_COUNT = "count";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_FNAME = "first_name";
private static final String TAG_ONAME = "other_names";
private static final String TAG_BRIEF = "description";
private static final String TAG_ID = "driver_id";
private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "location";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_CLASSA = "classA";
private static final String TAG_CLASSB = "classB";
private static final String TAG_CLASSC = "classC";
private static final String TAG_CLASSD = "classD";
private static final String TAG_CLASSE = "classE";

// Bundle key names
private static final String KEY_ID = "advert_id";
private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "advert_location";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "advert_name";
private static final String KEY_BRIEF = "advert_brief";
private static final String KEY_PHONE = "advert_phone";

ListView driverslist;
Driver advert;

boolean loadingMore;
int currentPage;
int itemCount;

public AvailableDriversFragment() {
    advert = new Driver();
    loadingMore = false;
    currentPage = 0;
    itemCount = 0;
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_availabledrivers,
            container, false);

    driverslist = (ListView) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.listView_availabledrivers);
    loadingmore = (TextView) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.availabledrivers_textView_more);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        currentPage = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentPage");
        itemCount = savedInstanceState.getInt("itemCount");
        Log.i("currentPage", "" + currentPage);
        driverslist.setAdapter(new DriversListAdapter(getActivity(),
                adverts));

    } else {
        new GetDrivers().execute();
    }

    driverslist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    driverslist.setOnScrollListener(this);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Fragment detailsFragment = new DriverDetailsFragment();
    advert = (Driver) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    int advert_id = advert.getId();
    String advert_location = advert.getLocation();
    String advert_brief = advert.getBrief();
    String advert_name = advert.getName();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(KEY_ID, advert_id);
    bundle.putString(KEY_LOCATION, advert_location);
    bundle.putString(KEY_NAME, advert_name);
    bundle.putString(KEY_BRIEF, advert_brief);

    detailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, detailsFragment)
            .addToBackStack("latest").commit();

}
}
```

Second fragment:

```
public class DriverJobsFragment extends Fragment implements
    OnItemClickListener, OnScrollListener {
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
ArrayList<CarItem> adverts;
TextView loadingmore;

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_COUNT = "count";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_HEADING = "tag";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG_ID = "item_id";
private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "location";
private static final String TAG_PHOTO = "photo";
private static final String TAG_MODEL = "model";
private static final String TAG_MAKE = "make";
private static final String TAG_REGISTRATION = "registration";
private static final String TAG_CATEGORY = "category";
private static final String TAG_TRANSMISSION = "transmission";
private static final String TAG_FUEL = "fuel";
private static final String TAG_ENGINE = "engine_size";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";

// Bundle key names
private static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "advert_description";
private static final String KEY_ID = "advert_id";
private static final String KEY_RATE = "advert_rate";
private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "advert_location";
private static final String KEY_FUEL = "advert_fuel";
private static final String KEY_ENGINE = "advert_engine";
private static final String KEY_MODEL = "advert_model";
private static final String KEY_MAKE = "advert_make";
private static final String KEY_TRANSMISSION = "advert_transmission";
private static final String KEY_REGISTRATION = "advert_registration";
private static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "advert_category";
private static final String KEY_PHONE = "advert_phone";

ListView jobslist;
CarItem advert;

boolean loadingMore;
int currentPage;
int itemCount;

public DriverJobsFragment() {
    advert = new CarItem();
    loadingMore = false;
    currentPage = 0;
    itemCount = 0;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_driverjobs,
            container, false);

    jobslist = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_driverjobs);
    loadingmore = (TextView) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.driverjobs_textView_more);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        currentPage = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentPage");
        itemCount = savedInstanceState.getInt("itemCount");
        Log.i("currentPage", "" + currentPage);
        jobslist.setAdapter(new CarsListAdapter(getActivity(), adverts));
    } else {
        new GetDriverJobs().execute();
    }

    jobslist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    jobslist.setOnScrollListener(this);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Fragment detailsFragment = new DriverJobDetailsFragment();
    advert = (CarItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    int advert_id = advert.getId();
    String advert_description = advert.getDescription();
    String advert_location = advert.getLocation();
    String advert_price = advert.getPrice();
    String advert_engine = advert.getEngineSize();
    String advert_model = advert.getModel();
    String advert_make = advert.getMake();
    String advert_transmission = advert.getTransmission();
    String advert_fuel = advert.getFuel();
    String advert_registration = advert.getRegistration();
    String advert_category = advert.getCategeory();
    String advert_phone = advert.getPhone();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(KEY_DESCRIPTION, advert_description);
    bundle.putInt(KEY_ID, advert_id);
    bundle.putString(KEY_RATE, advert_price);
    bundle.putString(KEY_LOCATION, advert_location);
    bundle.putString(KEY_ENGINE, advert_engine);
    bundle.putString(KEY_MODEL, advert_model);
    bundle.putString(KEY_MAKE, advert_make);
    bundle.putString(KEY_TRANSMISSION, advert_transmission);
    bundle.putString(KEY_FUEL, advert_fuel);
    bundle.putString(KEY_REGISTRATION, advert_registration);
    bundle.putString(KEY_CATEGORY, advert_category);
    bundle.putString(KEY_PHONE, advert_phone);

    detailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, detailsFragment)
            .addToBackStack("jobs_details").commit();

}
}
```

And the host fragment:

```
public class DriversFragment extends Fragment implements OnTabChangeListener,
    OnPageChangeListener {

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private DriverTabsAdapter mAdapter;
private TabHost mTabHost;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drivers, container,
            false);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.drivers_pager);

    // Tab Initialization
    mTabHost = (TabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    DriversFragment.AddTab(getActivity(), this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost
            .newTabSpec("jobs").setIndicator("Driver Jobs"));
    DriversFragment.AddTab(getActivity(), this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost
            .newTabSpec("drivers").setIndicator("Drivers"));
    mAdapter = new DriverTabsAdapter(getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager());
    // Fragments and ViewPager Initialization
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    return view;
}

// Manages the Tab changes, synchronizing it with Pages
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
}

// Manages the Page changes, synchronizing it with Tabs
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    int pos = this.mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(pos);
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
}

// Method to add a TabHost
private static void AddTab(Activity activity, TabHost tabHost,
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec) {
    tabSpec.setContent(new MyTabFactory(activity));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

}
```

Comment: show some code of what you do

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
That's because of lifecycle. When the back button is pressed, it goes to **onResume()**.
Not to **onCreateView()**. That's your problem. 
Move some code to onResume() such as **listview.setAdpater(adp)**.
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and declare a static ArrayList in it. Store all your data in it and populate your ListView through it. The data will persist till the time your application is running. This method may solve your problem.